# Multiple Collection Queries in Template

Tags: meteor

So I have this:

```
Template.cards.cards = function () {
  var deck = Deck.findOne({active: 1});
  var cards = Cards.find({deck_id: deck['_id']}).fetch();
  return cards;
}
```

But "deck" is returning undefined, even though calling the same query from the browser console returns results.

I feel like this is a reactivity issue and there is something fundamentally wrong with how I'm going about achieving this. It feels like a very relational way to go about things, I'm new to non-relational data storage too. I feel like there might be something fundamentally wrong with the way I'm going about this but I'm new to Meteor, I've trawled through the docs but can't find where I might be going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to access your `Deck` subscription right away at startup, it's possible that the data hasn't loaded yet. You can use a callback in the `subscribe` method to ensure you have data:

```
Meteor.subscribe("deck", function () {
    Session.set("activeDeck", 1);
};

Template.cards.cards = function () {
    var deck = Deck.findOne({ active: Session.get("activeDeck") });
    var cards = Cards.find({ deck_id: deck['_id'] }).fetch();
    return cards;
};
```

Perhaps you want to change this to subscribe to `decks` and then store a deck id instead of just an active flag in your session.

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI: the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) is misleading. The callback fires when the publish marks it as complete, but there is no guarantee that all the data has arrived at the client, only that the data has started to arrive.

Comment: This did it for me! Thanks! Although I did have to tweak it a little, added an if checking whether deck was set before running the query on Cards to avoid getting an error trying to access a property on an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

**[1]** First of all, check the datatype of `active` you are passing. If it is a string then `{active: 1}` will result in `false` and the query will return no results. And the `deck` will remain `undefined` .

**[2]** Try alternative way of `findOne` as : `Deck.find({active: 1}).fetch()[0];` This will return same result as `Deck.findOne({active: 1});`

**[3]** The`findOne()` and `find().fetch()[0]` returns **object which has properties** and the valid way of referencing the property of objects is `objectName.propertyName`, So replace `deck['_id']` with `deck._id` in `Cards.find({deck_id: deck['_id']}).fetch();`

Comment: Tried all of these, the datatype of active is right. The query is still running from the console and:
   Deck.findOne({active: 1})._id
Is returning the id like it should. It's just not cooperating inside the script.

Comment: Are you doing this with `autopublish`? If this is the case, your script code (and the query) will get executed before the collections are loaded from the server, and the query will return `undefined` .